# What are four types of authoritative cognition according to Chandrakirti?

Tags: mulamadhyamakakarika

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhyamaka) says this:

*Therefore we assert that mundane objects are known through the four kinds of **authoritative cognition**. They are mutually dependent: when there is authoritative cognition, there are objects of knowledge; when there are objects of knowledge, there is authoritative cognition. But neither authoritative cognition nor objects of knowledge exist inherently.[69]*

same page says this:

*Buddhism accepts only two pramana (tshad ma) as valid means to knowledge: Pratyaksha (mngon sum tshad ma, perception) and Anumāṇa (rjes dpag tshad ma, inference).*

Regardless, what are those four kinds of authoritative cognition according to Chandrakirti?

Comment: https://studybuddhism.com/en/advanced-studies/science-of-mind/ways-of-knowing/lorig-ways-of-knowing